# How can I turn off GLaDOS's voice in Portal using the console?

Tags: portal

I would like to find out because I was playing around in noclip and
GLaDOS's voice is annoying (in Test Chamber 19).

Comment: Could just turn your speakers down...

Comment: Can't blame her; she is annoying you with her voice while you're annoying her by using cheats :P

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to shut her up for good, you could 'mod' the game with a bunch of empty sound files, but from the console, the best I can come up with is the `stopsound` command.  Bind a key to it (e.g. `bind q stopsound`) and tap it whenever dialogue starts to end it immediately.

Comment: Or add it to a movement key (and other keys that is regularly used in the game).  Then there wouldn't be a need to have a separate key.